# html2canvas not showing complete contents in the captured image

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am using Flask as framework with HTML , javascript for front end . I am displaying a graph in my front end . However I want to download image of that graph . I am using HTML2canvas for that . Follwing is my code .

```
    <div class="hello" id="section" >
    <p>hi</p>
    <object type="text/html" data="/hello" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%; " autosize=True>
        </object>
    </div>

<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/>
    <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
    <br/>
    <h3>Preview :</h3>
    <div id="previewImage">
    </div>
```

I am using following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var element = $("#section"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable

    $("#btn-Preview-Image").on('click', function () {
         html2canvas(element, {
         onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                getCanvas = canvas;
             }
         });
    });

  $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "your_pic_name.png").attr("href", newData);
  });

         });
</script>
```

But I am getting only "hi" (due to "p tag") in my image and not the contents of "object tag " (actually using object tag I am embedding a URL , so contents being displayed due to that URL are not being captured in the image) . Can someone help me on that . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?